# Setting points for JButton pressed

Tags: java

I'm creating a game like jeopardy where you have the buttons from each row worth points ranging from 500 - 100. What I'm stuck on his how to add these points to the current score. Here's what I have:

```
public class GUIWindow implements ActionListener{
Players p1 = new Players();
  private int p1Score = 0;  
    private int p2Score = 0;


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
int points = 0;    
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     if(e.getSource() == boardButtonsRow1[i]){
       points = 500;
     }else if(e.getSource() == boardButtonsRow2[i]){
       points = 400;
     }else if(e.getSource() == boardButtonsRow3[i]){
       points = 300;
     }else if(e.getSource() == boardButtonsRow4[i]){
       points = 200;    
     }else if(e.getSource() == boardButtonsRow2[i]){
       points = 100;    
    } 
   
}
                      
if(e.getSource() == submitBtn){
String answer = answerEntry.getText();
    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(q1.getAnswer())){
                       
         System.out.println("Correct");
         System.out.println(points);
         p1Score = p1Score + points;
         p1.setPoints(p1Score);
         showP1ScoreLbl.setText(""+p1.getScore());
      
    }

}
```

The buttons are stored in rows and setup in arrays. I have a player class that stores the points (p1). When the user presses the submit button it checks if the answer is correct and adds this number of points to the label on my GUI. I don't know what I'm missing here but even when the answer is right it still shows 0.

Comment: You need to move `int points = 0;` outside of the `actionPerformed` method so that it becomes a class variable that will retain the value between method calls, just like the other score values `private int p1Score = 0;`. For this to work make sure that you set the points back to 0 at the end of the submitBtn method `points = 0;`

Comment: I'd like to see `setPoints()` and `getScore()` - are you sure these two are working correctly? And why the different names for the getter and setter? Finally, how does `Players pl` know which player's score you are adding? (And I think you should redesign it)